# Two different model attributes, with the same name, each passed to a different view, but in the same controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, el

Basically, I have a controller and two different account types. I want to display the view as  "adminDashboard.jsp" or "userDashboard.jsp", depending on the user's type, and pass a model attribute called "user" to each of these views, but with a different object with a different class depending on which view gets displayed. Currently, even though it's buried in a switch case, my code only reads whichever happens first, and not whichever one belongs to the "activated" switch.

HomeController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard")
public ModelAndView showDashboard(String userGroup) {
  switch(userGroup) {
    case "admin": {
      ModelAndView("adminDashboard", "user", adminObject);
    }
    case "user": {
      ModelAndView("userDashboard", "user", userObject);
    }
  }
}
```

adminDashboard.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ${user.adminId} <!-- reads this correctly -->
  ${user.userId} <!-- does not read this, which is good. -->
</body>
</html>
```

userDashboard.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ${user.adminId} <!-- reads this, which it should not -->
  ${user.userId} <!-- does not read this, but it should -->
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain to me why the admin user model attribute is still being passed, even though technically the code shouldn't even be going into that switch case? Is what I am trying to do even possible? If so, what would be an example?

Comment: suppose your switch case has issues.It does not contain `break;`you can try the same logic with `if else` block.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested, and still, even though it returns the userDashboard view, it uses the admin user model attribute when I use the ${user} EL tag. Very vexing, as the model attribute is only declared in the ModelAndView object associated with the OTHER view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining two jsp pages for user profile level, I suggest you to look at the use of JSTL If Else condition

```
 <c:if test="${user.profileLevel=='admin'}">
    <c:out value="${user.adminId}" />
    </c:if>
```

And if you want to make rendering on the sub user levels, you can use

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${user.profile=='partner'}">
      Partners with Us.
    </c:when>    
    <c:otherwise>
      Other Level.
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

can be nested within  condition.

In this scenario, your jsp will take care of the parameters being accessed. For me this would sound to be a better approach as accessing adminId in user level page shouldn't happen at the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, my example is just that, and this solution does not help me. There are about 10+ reasons why I need to do it the way I've outlined in the OP, most of which are out of my hands entirely. Please let me know if there is a solution to the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller as below :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard")
public ModelAndView showDashboard(String userGroup) {
  switch(userGroup) {
    case "admin": {
      ModelAndView("adminDashboard", "adminUser", adminObject);
      break;
    }
    case "user": {
      ModelAndView("userDashboard", "user", userObject);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And in your adminDashboard.jsp access it as below:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
      ${adminUser.adminId} <!-- reads like this -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the conditions of the question. I need to not have adminUser and user, but simply just user. My menu navigation is 1000000% dependent on this, and that is not up to me. Please let me know if there is a solution that fits what I asked.